# Setting search_path in sql dump

Tags: postgresql, database-schema, psql, search-path

In a `psql` dump from a database using pg_dump version 11.4, the search_path is set as follows:

```sql
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
```

I am attempting to another schema (i.e. not `public`), and make this new schema the default one for a particular role by setting `search_path`. In other words:

```sql
ALTER ROLE myrole IN DATABASE mydatabase SET search_path TO myschema,public;
```

Currently, even though I can log into psql as that role and verify that `search_path` has been set using `SELECT * FROM current_setting('search_path');` I cannot get that alteration to be exported in the dump, which means I have to assume that it has been set properly.

However, I'd like that to be done as a command in a dump file using `pg_dump` rather than set it myself in `psql` and implicitly assume it has been set properly. Can this be done? Is there a setting in `pg_dump` that I'm missing?

Comment: People may find it useful to invoke `psql` as `PGOPTIONS=--search_path=some_schema psql` .  Via: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/171964/45101

Answer (score 1):

Roles (users) are global to the Postgres instance (aka "cluster", aka "data directory") and shared across all databases in that instance.

`pg_dump` does not dump global objects, because it only dumps the database content.

To see the change for your role, you would need to dump the "globals" using `pg_dumpall`

```
pg_dumpall --globals-only -f globals.sql
```

Comment: What about if I'm trying to do this command for a role on another server where I don't run as root? It seems this command requires certain privileges that my role doesn't have.

Comment: How about `ALTER DATABASE ... SET search_path ...`? Why is it not dumped as well?